# How to setSelectedItem of Jcombobox Programmatically with a DisplayValueModel in Java

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox populated with an object of a custom class DisplayValueModel.

The Class:

```
public class DisplayValueModel {
    public Object displayMember;
    public Object valueMember;

    public DisplayValueModel(Object display, Object value) {
        displayMember = display;
        valueMember = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return displayMember.toString();
    }
}
```

The code to fill combobox:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    id = rs.getInt("ID");
    Author = rs.getString("FullName");
    DisplayValueModel cb = new DisplayValueModel(Author,id);
    MainAuthor.addItem(cb);
}
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
DisplayValueModel cb = new DisplayValueModel("Harlan Coben" ,1);
MainAuthor.setSelectedItem(cb);
```

So, how do I set the item in the combobox? Ideally I would like to be able to set it only with the id, like:

```
MainAuthor.setSelectedItem(id)
```

Where id is an Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preamble: Please, please, please respect the Java naming conventions. Your code is hard to read because you're not.

That said, here's what the javadoc of setSelectedItem() says:

> Sets the selected item in the combo box display area to the object in the argument. If anObject is in the list, the display area shows anObject selected.
>
> If anObject is not in the list and the combo box is uneditable, it will not change the current selection.

That should be obvious, but the javadoc says it anyway: you can't possibly make an element selected if the element is not even in the list.

So, in order for the following code to select something:

```
DisplayValueModel cb = new DisplayValueModel("Harlan Coben", 1);
mainAuthor.setSelectedItem(cb);
```

then `cb` must be equal to one of the element in the list. Equality in Java is defined by the Object.equals() method. So, either override equals() (and hashCode()) in DisplayValueModel, or simply *find* the element in the combo box that has the ID you want to select, and then call setSelectedItem with this found element.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, there is nothing wrong with my code, because the cb element I created here is in the list exactly the same way... But when I want setSelectedItem to work on only an ID, I only have to override the equals() and hashCode() method?

Comment: I find it bizarre, and it's probably the sign of a design error, that you try selecting an item that is not in the list. But yes, you can override equals() and hashCode().

Comment: Can you give an example of how to override these methods?

Comment: Google is your friend. The javadoc is your friend. Your IDE is your friend. All IDEs have wizards to override equals() and hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

Normally you wont give your data only to a view and dont keep it in the date model. So in your case you will only have access to the list by looking at the views combobox. That's no good style.

Keep your list in the model, which meeans do not give the list directly to the combobox, but store it into any variable in your data model and then fill the combobox with this list. Then you can always access it and get the index of each item by searching for the displayMember or displayValue.

Answer (score 0):

I used the wizard to override the equals() and hashCode() methods (see answer/comment of JB Nizet) which resulted in the following code:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + ((valueMember == null) ? 0 : valueMember.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((displayMember == null) ? 0 : displayMember.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    DisplayValueModel other = (DisplayValueModel) obj;
    if (displayMember == null) {
        if (other.displayMember != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!displayMember.equals(other.displayMember))
        return false;
    if (valueMember == null) {
        if (other.valueMember != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!valueMember.equals(other.valueMember))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

These methods are added to the DisplayValueModel class.
Now the setSelectedItem(cb) does work.